# Getting information from a different dataSource to update my own on Grails

Tags: grails, design-patterns, decorator, observer-pattern, multiple-databases

I have an app, with its own datasource, that needs to get "Item" objects from a different datasource, a readonly one, and use this Items and add them some attributes and collections of "Part" and "Process" objects, so I'm considering three options:

1. Creating an object with 2 datasources that somehow reads from the readonly database but updates in my database
2. Creating a trigger in the readonly database that creates an object in my database when someone inserts, updates or deletes something there.
3. Create two objects one pointing to the readonly database and other pointing to my database and use the decorator pattern to be able to get info from the other database and functionality with my object

I think the easiest one is the trigger in the readonly database cause I don't see how to implement an observer with a factory to create my own objects, to implement options one or three, and I'm not sure if there's a better way, so, what would be the best way of implementing this? how could options 1 or 3 could be implemented? is there something like a "findAllFromHereThatIsntThere" Gorm method that I could call?

Thanks

Comment: The solution depends on how data is being populated in your readonly db, I could not say that by your explanations. Or what would be the trigger for your application to read the readonly tables and populate new data?

Comment: The read only db its going to be populated by a different program, so for me their tables are going to be read only and the other program is going to be the owner, so, I really can't modify that info or that program, but, I have access to the db, that way, I can create a trigger in the MS SQL server that would populate my db, but I prefer doing all the programming from my app and not mixing programs here and there for a better code and easy maintenance.

Comment: If you go with trigger, which makes sense in this case, then to be clear and not mixing functionality you can define 2 series of domains, one the ones that are mapped with your readonly db, and those that write into your application database. The coding part of it is straightforward, you can read from origin, do your modification and save in your application database.

Comment: The observer you are talking about would be overcompleting your design imo, but you can have background jobs ex.`quartz` to check for changes and update your database. But again this is less efficient than db trigger in your case unless you have a good reason.

Comment: I'm going to do it that way, post an answer so I can accept it. Tks!!!, I'll let you know how it works! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using database trigger on the external database, the logic in your application is very straightforward. On your application you can have domains mapping the readonly database and domains for your local db. This will help to separating the concern for each domain. The logic for manipulating the data and storing them in your application database can be inside a transactional service.

Grails provides great features for [multiple databases](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) that can be utilized here.

Hope it helps